# impoly become slow in MATLAB deployed standalone application

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment, impoly

I'm building a standalone guide application which uses `impoly` inside.

When I drag the vertices of polygon created using `impoly` or drag the polygon itself, there's noticeable delay for actions, this doesn't happen in the MATLAB script file.

Even a simple script like the code below will create the delay after being converted to executable.

```
figure, imshow('peppers.png')
h = impoly(gca, []);
```

What is causing the delay here, and how can I solve this?

I know that using self defined drawing functions and `windowbutton` functions is faster but I don't want to lose the ease of using an `impoly` object because it's handled by internal codes.

The compiler version is R2011a.

**Updates**:

Not only `impoly` becomes slow when deployed. All rendering of graphic objects become slow. Pan tool and zoom tools have delays as well.
The solution is using `uiwait` to block the execution before exit. But I don't know why that solves the problem.